# Bad Gateway Ngrok?

Tags: ngrok

I am trying out the dev for FB Messenger bots and need a web hook. I have been trying Ngrok, but I keep getting a `502 bad gateway error.`

I tried `./ngrok http 3000` and I used the url `http://a0b3abcb.ngrok.io` as a callback, but it refuses saying `HTTP bad gateway.`

What is wrong and how do I fix this? MAC OSX.

Answer (score 4):

Found a fix.

I ran a Django server on port 8000 (default) and ran NGROK on port 8000 instead of port 80. Basically, if the port # is the same on the server and Ngrok, then you have a solution.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to solve your problem. Just saw this now